# VLine Firefox Chrome Call

Tags: vline

I am having trouble with calls placed/received from Firefox v27 to Chrome v32

One computer is behind a corporate firewall (Chrome) & the other is on a separate wireless network (Firefox).

Chrome to Chrome calls work flawlessly but when firefox is involved I do not receive the persons video, I get a local preview stream but not the other side.

There are no errors except a warning( [vline.media] Unknown system constraint minbitrate) in the console and VLine believes we are connected I just don't get their stream.

Tried calling through my application , and then just using 2 VLine pages with no success.

How can I go about troubleshooting this?. Known troubles with Firefox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox doesn't support TCP ICE candidates: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=891551. It's likely that the firewalls involved are blocking UDP, and since Firefox isn't using TCP candidates it's unable to connect.

Comment: Knew it wasn't vline.I will check firewall rules which is probably the issue and let you know. Thanks.